# How to associate navigation drawer to dragger button out side?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm not sure if this is common question, I couldn't find anything on similar but perhaps I just don't name it right..

**Brief explanation:**

I'm trying to attach to my navigation drawer, a button (floating button) outside of it so the button is visible even when the drawer is close, so dragging the button opens the drawer..

**Real app example:**

Some apps like *Waze* have that:

[image]

**My trying..**

So before I go crazy and setup touch listeners and annoying stuffs, I tried to go simple first.. I tried to simply add button inside the NavigationView on the xml file..

Heres my acivity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="-80dp"
            android:text="drag me->" />

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

I've also made sure to add this line to the parent:

```
android:clipChildren="false"
```

(so the button will be able to cross out of the boundries..)

And here's what it looks like (on the preview):

[image]

On real testing the button is indeed on the placement like in the picture but if the drawer is completely closed, the button disappear..

If I open the drawer just a little bit the button is then becomes visible..

Anyway, the button doesn't response to touch.. I can't close the drawer by dragging the button..

So.. what can I do to fix this? Am I even close? or I should start cursing some touch listeners?

Thanks ahead!

Comment: did you implement this . i'm looking for the same implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

put your button outside the Navigation View

```
button.setOnClikclistener({


drawer.closeDrawer(GRAVITY) / drawer.openDrawer(GRAVITY)
  }
```

if You want the Button to move along the edge of Drawer , you have implement separate behaviour for  Button using Coordinator layout and stuffs

this can come in Handy https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/customizing-coordinatorlayouts-behavior/

Comment: Thank you but thats not what I was asking for.. opening the drawer by click is an easy task.. I want to open it gradually while I drag the button.. just like dragging the edge will open the drawer along with my finger, but instead I will use the snipping button as helper..